Dimension of the range of a tensor product
To show that there are indecomposable tensors, we define the bilinear mapping:
$$\theta:L\times M \rightarrow N$$
Where $L$ & $M$ are vector spaces of dimensions $l$ & $m$ and $N$ is the linear space where $\theta(e_i,e'_j) := e_i\otimes e'_j$ are all different basis vectors (by construction of $\theta$ and $N$). To show there are indecomposable tensors we have to show that $\theta(L\times M)$ has lower dimension that $N$ itself. Clearly:
$$\text{dim}(N)=lm$$
since that's the number of basis vectors. However now my professor writes the following:
$$\text{dim}(\theta(L\times M))=\dim(L\times M)-1=l+m-1$$
I couldn't understand where that "$-1$" term comes from and when I asked him, he said it's because of the bilinearity of $\theta$ and wrote "$\theta(ax,y)=\theta(x,ay)=a\theta(x,y)$". How does this property lead to one less degree of freedom?

Notice, for example, that when $\dim M=1$, the $\dim L$ vectors $(e_i,e_1')$ determine the image.

Do you perhaps mean indecomposable? Your map $\theta$ exactly gives decomposable tensors.

Yes I mean indecomposable. Also @TedShifrin your example only makes me more strongly convinced that the "$-1$" shouldn't be there

No, on the contrary. You need $l + 1 - 1 = l$.

oh yes I get it. However what about if both spaces have dimension of two? How is then the image 3-dimensional?

Or moreover can you show me a case where $\text{dim}(L\times N) > \text{dim}(R(\theta))$?

As other people are pointing out, when $\dim L$ and $\dim M$ are both bigger than $1$, the image of $\theta$ is not a linear subspace, so I'm not sure what your professor means by dimension. But, following his remark to you, notice that $\theta(tx,(1/t)y)$ is constant, so this gives a constraint.  But his dimension claim is suspect in general.

Your $N$ is what's usually written as $L \otimes M$. The map $\theta$ is bilinear, not linear, and the image of a bilinear map need not be a subspace, so talking about the dimension of the image of a bilinear map is awkward.
In particular, the set of decomposable tensors in $L \otimes M$ is not usually a subspace of $L \otimes M$.
An example of a tensor that is provably not decomposable occurs when $\dim L = \dim M = 2$.  Let $L$ have basis $e_1, e_2$ and $M$ have basis $e_1', e_2'$. In $L \otimes M$, $e_1 \times e_1' + e_2 \otimes e_2'$ is an indecomposable tensor. See Example 4.11 here: there let $R = \mathbf R$ and $F$ and $F'$ be two $n$-dimensional real vector spaces where $n \geq 2$.

Well when I asked him about the image and the cartesian product not being vector spaces he said that the dimension is in the sense of manifolds which is a strange answer considering I don't remember studying what is a manifold. (I guess it is meant by some sort of counting the degrees of freedom?)

That, too, is sloppy. The set of decomposable tensors is a cone, and rarely is the origin a smooth point of a cone. So this will almost be a manifold, but not quite.
